# html2pdf how to add footer in each page?

Tags: php, tcpdf, html2pdf

i have gone through their example, but in my case i am including the lot  of html documents,so i couldn't use that

below is the sample code i am using

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf-new/vendor/autoload.php');
    //$pdf=new HTML2FPDF("P","mm","A4");
$pdf=new HTML2PDF("P","A4","en");

    //$pdf->AddPage();
    $file="pdfs/$id"."_test.html";
    $fp = fopen($file,"r");
    $strContent = fread($fp, filesize($file));
    $pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);

    //$pdf->AddPage();
    $file="pdfs/$id"."_ptest.html";
    $fp = fopen($file,"r");
    $strContent = fread($fp, filesize($file));
    $pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);

    //$pdf->AddPage();
    $file="pdfs/$id"."_ftest.html";
    $fp = fopen($file,"r");
    $strContent = fread($fp, filesize($file));
    $pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
    $pdf->Output("pdfs/$subempid.pdf");
```